# How can I get multiple file uploads working in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following in my controller that worked fine in Rails 4:

```
def create_multiple
  params[:documents].map do |document|
    if document[:upload]
      doc = Document.new
      doc.upload = document[:upload]
      doc.category_id = @category.id
      doc.save
    end
  end
  redirect_to @category, notice: 'Documents saved'
end
```

Now, after upgrading to Rails 5, it doesn't work. I strongly suspect this is because [params is now an Object, rather than HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://eileencodes.com/posts/actioncontroller-parameters-now-returns-an-object-instead-of-a-hash/), but I can't figure out how to make the multiple file upload work again.

Tried this:

```
params.to_unsafe_h[:documents].map do |document|
```

But then it fails with `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` for the
`if document[:upload]` part.

Any ideas on how I can move forward on this?

Comment: It seems that `document` is an array? Can't you validate that with a `debugger` or some logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had to rework my form to be more "railsy" for this to work in Rails 5, in Slim (in the new_multiple view):

```
= form_tag create_multiple_category_documents_path(@category), multipart: true do
  .row.bottom30
    - @documents.each_with_index do |document, ndx|
      = fields_for 'documents[]', document, index: ndx do |f|
        .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.bottom30
          => f.label :title
          = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'
          = f.file_field :upload
```

And here's what's now in the controller:

```
def new_multiple
  @documents = 20.times.map { @category.documents.build }
end

def create_multiple
  params[:documents].each do |num, document|
    unless document[:upload].blank?
      doc = Document.new
      doc.upload = document[:upload]
      doc.category_id = @category.id
      doc.save
    end
  end
  redirect_to @category, notice: 'Documents saved'
end
```

There's probably a better way to do this, but this works for now.